# Setting logstash-compatible logging patterns in Apache Storm Workers

Tags: logging, log4j2, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have some difficulties getting Storm worker/topology logs into an ELK-compatible format (JSON) with Storm 2.1.0.

These are my current worker logging configs:

`cluster.xml`

```xml
<Configuration monitorInterval="60" shutdownHook="disable" packages="ch.qos.logback.core">
    <Properties>
        <property name="logstash">+ %msg +%n</property> <!-- only for 'bug' demonstration purposes -->
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${logstash}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

`worker.xml`

```xml
<Configuration monitorInterval="60" shutdownHook="disable" packages="ch.qos.logback.core">
        <Properties>
            <property name="logstash">{"@timestamp":"%d{yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS}", "logger": "%logger", "message":"%msg","thread_name":"%t","level":"%level"}%n</property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE">
            <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>${logstash}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.com.package" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

According to my this configuration, I would've expected a log message formatted similarly to the following (newlines added for clarity:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2020-02-11 11:32:40,748",
  "logger": "org.com.package.aggregation.SomeAggregation",
  "message": "joinStateStream: values: [33333333-4e30-49a6-8e1c-f7817633bb34, 7c777777-a622-4ae4-a504-2490db47cafe, 2020-02-11]",
  "thread_name": "Thread-23-b-25-joinState-groupedQ-revQ-executor[22, 22]",
  "level": "DEBUG"
}
```

However, it seems like the messages are being "wrapped" by either the supervisor process or even the worker itself. The log messages I get look like the following instead:

(newlines/whitespace added for readability)

```
+ Worker Process 273c05df-f087-43ca-a59a-e281bae98ab1:  
{  
    "@timestamp":"2020-02-11 11:32:40,748",
    "logger": "STDERR",
    "message":
        "{
            "@timestamp":"2020-02-11 11:32:40,748",
            "logger": "org.com.package.aggregation.SomeAggregation",
            "message":"joinStateStream: values: [33333333-4e30-49a6-8e1c-f7817633bb34, 7c777777-a622-4ae4-a504-2490db47cafe, 2020-02-11]",
            "thread_name":"Thread-23-b-25-joinState-groupedQ-revQ-executor[22, 22]",
            "level":"DEBUG"
        }",  
    "thread_name":"Thread-2",
    "level":"INFO"} +
```

Several things seem to be happening here (going inward):

1. The supervisor seems to wrap all worker messages and prepend them with `Worker Process <worker-id>:`. This can be noted by the `+` that wraps the entire message.
2. The worker seems to wrap its own log messages somehow. The `message` part of the log contains yet another log message.

As for my questions:

1. Can I disable this supervisor log prefixing? Looking at the source code in `org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.BasicContainer#launch`, this seems to be hardcoded. I can't imagine that a correct topology deployment should result in a *hardcoded prefix* that is added to every log message.
2. How can this worker message wrapping happen? As I can see, the 'wrappee' is my actual topology message (that I wish to parse), and the 'wrapper' is something else entirely (with logger `STDERR`? Why is it logging to `STDERR`? With level `INFO`???)

Basically, I want to simply log some messages during the execution of my topology and control the format of these messages. How can I do this reliably with Storm?

Comment: Just wondering if you considered swapping `PatternLayout` with [JSONLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout)?

Comment: I have not tried that. I'll do so and get back to you. Thank you for the suggestion.